# App storage space on Kindle Fire HD

Tags: android, kindle-fire

On the Kindle Fire HD 7", accessing Settings->Applications->Installed Applications->(App Name) takes me to an **Application Details** page. On this page, there are a number of storage stats. I can't seem to find any documentation as to what these are. I need to understand what each one is exactly in-order to debug certain storage issues for an app that I'm developing for the Kindle.

Would be great if someone could provide a description for each line item. The application details page has the following stats:

**Storage**

---

Total ..................... 63.95 MB

App .......................  52.61 MB

USB storage app .......  0.00 B

Data ......................  11.05 MB

Storage device  ......... 304 KB

**Cache**

---

Cache  ..................... 688 KB

Answer (score 0):

For details of the implementation, you can check the following information from Android developer guide:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

As defined in "App" row, your app's "binary" (it's not only the binary, I am using it in a rough way to define all runtime components) is stored in Internal Storage. The user-based data is also in Internal Storage as defined in "Data" row.

What you see is actually a standard Android App Info screen. For an in-depth definition of what each row means, you can refer to the following Stack Exchange question:

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32678/what-is-usb-storage-app-under-storage-of-app-info